# Pass a pandas writer object to a function

Tags: python, pandas, function

I'm trying to pass an Excel writer object into a function to write variations of the same results (daily, weekly and monthly frequencies), but nothing seems to get written inside the function.

I start by creating an Excel writer object:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfn)
IRdaily.to_excel(writer, 'Interest Rates')
writer.save()
```

So far so good - this works like a charm, and the table of interest rates get. I now pass my results, along with the writer object into a function which is defined as follows:

```
def writeResults(writer, DailyWeeklyMonthly, deltaIR):
    pd.DataFrame([DailyWeeklyMonthly + ' Changes in Interest Rates']).to_excel(writer, DailyWeeklyMonthly + ' Changes', startrow = 0, startcol=0,  header=False, index=False)    
    deltaIR.to_excel(writer,DailyWeeklyMonthly + ' Changes', startrow = 1)
    writer.save()
```

I write text strings by the crude artifice of creating an dataframe from the string (pd.DataFrame([DailyWeeklyMonthly + ' Changes in Interest Rates']) ) and then writing it to the appropriate point in a worksheet that the writer objects needs to create.

If I call this function as follows

```
writeResults(writer, 'Daily', deltaIRDaily)
```

Nothing gets written - the worksheet 'Daily Changes' does not even get created. However, if I don't pass the writer to the writeResults function and instead write

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outfn)
IRdaily.to_excel(writer, 'Interest Rates')
pd.DataFrame(['Daily Changes in Interest Rates']).to_excel(writer, 'Daily Changes', startrow = 0, startcol=0,  header=False, index=False)    
deltaIR.to_excel(writer,'Daily Changes', startrow = 1)

writer.save()
```

the code works just fine! What am I doing wrong when I pass the writer object to the writeResults function? I'm doing this so that I can write results at various frequencies (Daily, Weekly, Monthly) with just a few lines of code.

Thank you in advance for your assistance

Thomas Philips

Comment: I do indeed have a writer.save()